# How to export vector layer containing polylines into polygons in Google Earth

Tags: polygon, export, kml, vector-layer, path

I'm using QGIS 3.16.5 Hannover and I already knew how to convert vector layer (from AutoCAD containing polylines) into KML format. When I export it as KML and open it up to Google Earth Pro, the resulting KML object is a path (not a polygon as I would want it to be). There is an option to set geometry type as polygon (in the export vector window) but it doesn't make any difference. How do I set it as polygon and not a path?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use **Vector - Geometry Tools - Lines to Polygon**. This will close all polylines (join the last point to the first).
2. Then export to KML

Comment: Thanks for the brief reply. There is no Polygon tool option, only lines to polygon and polygon to lines. Which of these please?

Comment: EDIT: i used the line to polyline feature and it worked great! Thanks for the advice. My tiny issue now is how to adjust thickness? Thanks for the answer!!!

Comment: Lines to Polygon - sorry, I was watching TV.

Comment: It is the display format in Google Earth rather than the underlying geometry from QGIS that needs to be changed if you want a different thickness.

Comment: I see. I thought there would be a setting to be changed to adjust thickness, it would have been a nice additional feature if it was available because I have lots of polygons to adjust thickness but its fine tho. Thank you and sorry to have bothered you watching TV :)